# SELECT a minimum amount of two types of data in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, select

I'm not sure how to give a code example, so I'll explain this as best I can.

I have a table column that gives the user's id plus websites they have. Each client can have multiple rows in the table.

Is it possible to give MySQL a minimum number of rows to retrieve of a particular id, if you have a set number of rows in your query?

So say you're selecting 10 rows all up, can you say "give me ten rows, with a minimum of 3 rows belonging to user 5, and if user 5 doesn't have 3 rows, just make up the 10 from the other users' rows".

Comment: you'd probably need at least two queries. one to fetch 3 <= x < 10 for the one user, figure out how many you got, then fetch the 10-x from other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I am missing something here is a query based on Marc B suggestion :

```
SELECT * FROM
  ( (SELECT * FROM userWebSites WHERE userId = 5 LIMIT 10)
    UNION
    (SELECT * FROM userWebSites WHERE userId <> 5 LIMIT 10) ) AS Merged 
LIMIT 10
```

However it will always return the same rows for the other users to fill up the missing rows.